# How to Load html file in to WebView from Device storage downloads folder

Tags: android, html, android-studio, android-intent, android-webview

My HTML file is a game file contains sounds images animations, I am able to retrieve the file but it is not playing. I know how to access it from project asset folder using:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/____/index.html");
```

but when I receive it from device storage from Download folder I'm unable to play the file in webview.

Below is the code to show up html files from Download folder :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
Uri uri = Uri.parse(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/Download");
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "text/html");
startActivityForResult(intent,PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE);
```

and in the onActivityResult I wrote like this :

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    switch (requestCode){
        case PICKFILE_RESULT_CODE :
            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                Uri uri1 = data.getData();
                File file1 = new File(uri1.getPath());
                final String[] split = file1.getPath().split(":");

                String filePath = split[1];

               /* after splitting it will be /storage/emulated/0/Download/index.html */

                if (filePath.endsWith(".html")){
                    mywebview.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
                    mywebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
                    mywebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
                    mywebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
                    mywebview.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                    mywebview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
                    mywebview.clearCache(true);
                    mywebview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());
                    mywebview.loadUrl(filePath);
                    mywebview.evaluateJavascript(filePath);
                }

            }
            break;
    }
}

private class WebViewClientClass extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
    }
}
```

So please correct me if I am doing anything wrong or tell me the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

There are several things to do.

1. Make sure the app has **READ** access and the app can access the correct file.
2. This is a **big security issue** so you should not read a **public** file and load it in your app.

Once you have the file, load its content.

You're also getting a `URI` in ActivityResult. You can't just convert URI to file. Use this to read the content of the file. (in Kotlin)

```
context.contentResolver.openInputStream(uri).reader().readText()
```

Once you have the content,

```
webview.loadData(content, MIME_TYPE, ENCODING)
```

where

```
MIME_TYPE = "text/html"
ENCODING = "utf-8"
```